# How can I get the Google Calendar app to sync more often?

Tags: google-calendar

I'm new to Android and am having an issue where the Google Calendar app seems to only sync with my Google Account every 3 or 4 days. This is a real pain as I often miss appointment and reminder alerts that I set via my desktop.

Is there a way to have this sync more frequently?

Comment: Well, 1st it's not the calendar app doing the sync (but the sync backend, whichever calendar app you're using), and 2nd that's really very unusual. AFAIK it should sync at least once a day (also see [here](https://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-4/258561-google-calendar-sync-interval.html)). If that's broken, I often read one should temporarily remove the Google account and re-add it. Maybe wait for someone who had this issue solved to give better advice, and keep this as a fallback. I cannot really tell as I no longer use Google cal/contacts for years already. I like to keep my data ;)

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you might have "limits" set on your "background data". try enabling instead of restricting it.

Comment: Your answer might be useful if you explain how to remove any limits, since the questioner clearly doesn't know about setting a limit.